# Resources not copied to bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, bundle

I have an XCode project for an iOS application, and added to it 3 small mp3's in the structure that are copied to the destination bundle upon compilation.

I have then added a bigger mp3's (4MB) to the structure (same folder than the previous ones) and into the Build Phases:
[image]
However upon compilation, this file is not present in the bundle. I tried to clean and recompile, change destination, but the file is still absent:
[image]

Anything I could have forgotten to check ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show a screenshot of the "Copy Resources" *Build Phase*.

Comment: Hmmm strange; your configuration looks OK.  Have you studied the *Build Log* (open up the relevant line using the icon thing on the righthand side).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I just started having this problem on a project that has been building fine for years and was building fine only a few hours ago. Now all of a sudden, files aren't getting copied.

Comment: When you click on the file in the main editor window, does it have a target checked on the inspector ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your build phase->resources and check these files are showing there or not and check when you add them did you allow them to **copy when required** checkbox was selected or not.

Comment: The file is already in the build phase resource and the copy checkbox was ticked (you are talking about the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)", right ?).

Answer (score 0):

When you add resources, make sure not only the **copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)** is ticked, but also tick the corresponding target in the **Add to targets** list.